# Restricting the domain of integer values accepted as input in python

Tags: python, optimization, input, one-liner

I'm building a command line game using python.A main feature of this game is to get the user's input of either 1 or 2 as integer values.Any other character must be rejected.I used `try-except` & `if-else condition` to do this like shown below.I want to know whether there is any better method to get this done in one line or some other way without having to indent a whole bunch of code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# INITIALIZE THE TOTAL STICKS , DEPTH OF THE TREE AND THE STARTINGG PLAYER
i_stickTotal = 11 # TOTAL NO OF STICKS IN THIS GAME
i_depth = 5 # THE DEPTH OF THE GOAL TREEE THE COMPUTER WILL BUILD
i_curPlayer = 1 # THIS WILL BE +1 FOR THE HUMAN AND -1 FOR THE COMPUTER
print("""There are 11 sticks in total.\nYou can choose 1 or 2 sticks in each turn.\n\tGood Luck!!""")
# GAME LOOP
while i_stickTotal > 0:
    print("\n{} sticks remain. How many would you pick?".format(i_stickTotal))
    try:
        i_choice = int(input("\n1 or 2: "))
        if  i_choice - 1 == 0 or i_choice - 2 == 0:            
            i_stickTotal -= int(i_choice)
            if WinCheck(i_stickTotal, i_curPlayer):
                i_curPlayer *= -1
                node = Node(i_depth, i_curPlayer, i_stickTotal)
                bestChoice = -100
                i_bestValue = -i_curPlayer * maxsize

                #   Determine No of Sticks to Remove

                for i in range(len(node.children)):
                    n_child = node.children[i]
                    #print("heres what it look like ", n_child.i_depth, "and",i_depth)
                    i_val = MinMax(n_child, i_depth-1, i_curPlayer)
                    if abs(i_curPlayer * maxsize - i_val) <= abs(i_curPlayer*maxsize-i_bestValue):
                        i_bestValue = i_val
                        bestChoice = i
                        #print("Best value was changed @ ", i_depth, " by " , -i_curPlayer, " branch ", i, " to ", i_bestValue)



                bestChoice += 1
                print("Computer chooses: " + str(bestChoice) + "\tbased on value: " + str(i_bestValue))
                i_stickTotal -= bestChoice
                WinCheck(i_stickTotal, i_curPlayer)
                i_curPlayer *= -1
            else:
                print("You can take only a maximum of two sticks.")

    except:
        print("Invalid input.Only Numeric Values are accepted")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to check user input and use below code.

```py
while True:
    var = int(input('Enter value (1 or 2) - '))
    if var not in range(1, 3):
        print('Invalid entry, please try again...')
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that loops, calling `input`, until the value satisfies your constraint. Perhaps call it `get_user_input`. Then call that in your main function instead of `input`. For added value, pass a lambda into that function as a predicate to test the user input value - that'll make `get_user_input` more general.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about using a lambda function.What do you exactly mean by 'make the get_user_input function more general'?